# Why wasn't "alzhéimer" adapted to "alcéimer" in Spanish?

Tags: ortografía, sustantivos, dle, rae, vocabulario-médico

Today's selected word in the RAE web is the following one:

> **[alzhéimer](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2B3Izdh)**
>
> De A. *Alzheimer*, 1864-1915, neurólogo alemán.
>
> 1. m. Med. enfermedad de Alzheimer.

I understand that *Alzheimer* is a proper name, and so in "enfermedad de Alzheimer" the proper name is used (note that it does not carry a *tilde* over the first *e*). But then a common name is created (*alzhéimer*) with the same meaning, so now it carries the *tilde*... and a *zh* group that does not belong to Spanish.

I have never seen anybody using *[tuit](http://dle.rae.es/?id=asqoMGb)*, but when the word *tweet* began to be of common use in Spanish, the RAE registered the word in its dictionary, but recommended to use the adapted form *tuit* (and not *twit*) as the *tw* group does not belong to Spanish. I understand that the same thing happened with *alzhéimer* as people just used the name of the neurologist to refer to it. But now the RAE did not adapt the term.

So why wasn't it adapted as *alcéimer*?

Comment: And not least: why the hell was the accent moved? The name in German has initial stress, which is maintained in English and other languages, and initial stress here would be perfectly possible in Spanish too… so why shift it to the second syllable?

Answer (score 6):

Si nos vamos a la Fundéu, [indican que](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/alzheimer-escritura-correcta-1079/):

> si se emplea este término aisladamente para referirse a dicha enfermedad, se convierte en un sustantivo común, por lo que ha de escribirse con minúscula inicial y con tilde: *alzhéimer*.

Pero eso solo explica el uso de tilde, no el que se mantenga la pareja *zh* tan ajena a nuestro idioma.

Consultando entonces el maravilloso recurso que es el [Fichero](http://web.frl.es/fichero.html), podemos ver que [alzhéimer [PDF]](http://web.frl.es/FICHERO/FICHERO/LETRA_A/LETRA_A_PDF/ALZHEIMER/00000235.pdf) ya estaba recogida con tilde en el *[Diccionario general y técnico hispanoamericano](http://vufind.uniovi.es/Record/529988)*, de 1930:

[image]

El motivo: que el propio apellido del psicólogo alemán, *Alzhéimer*, también lo escribían con tilde. Se comprende entonces que, siendo la palabra una simple sustantivación del apellido, se mantuviese la escritura tal cual.

**Si la RAE introdujo la palabra en el DLE a través de este otro diccionario, y si en 1930 el término ya estaba en uso médico con tilde, es normal que no se quisiera modificar su escritura, pues llevaría a confusiones innecesarias** en un campo (el de la Medicina) que no está para esas cosas.

Sobre que se escribiese el apellido con tilde... Lo cierto es que, hoy en día, Alzheimer se escribe sin tilde tanto en español y alemán, como en inglés, francés, portugués o italiano.
Pero también es cierto que, hasta no hace tantos años, había cierta tendencia a "castellanizar" los nombres y apellidos extranjeros (siendo el "Wolfango Amadeo Mozart" de varias enciclopedias el primer caso que me viene a la mente).
Siguiendo este razonamiento, encuentro [un par de resultados en Google Books](https://www.google.es/search?hl=es&biw=1280&bih=918&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1900%2Ccd_max%3A1999&tbm=bks&q=Alzh%C3%A9imer&oq=Alzh%C3%A9imer&gs_l=psy-ab.12...0.0.0.18099.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.m6ZpA1btMAY), en francés y portugués, que escriben el apellido con tilde. Puede que en otros idiomas sucediese lo mismo que indico y que la grafía en español del siglo pasado estuviese influenciada por estos idiomas; o puede que simplemente fuese un intento de indicar que se pronuncia `Al'zheimer` (llana) y no `Alzhei'mer` (aguda).

Comment: Esta respuesta es muchísimo mejor que [la que me ha dado la RAE](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/910817602657714176) en Twitter...

Comment: Tampoco hay una norma clara en estos casos de epónimos como explican en [wikilengua](http://www.wikilengua.org/index.php/Ep%C3%B3nimo)

Comment: [Pues insisten en lo mismo](https://twitter.com/RAEinforma/status/910831579202715648): "prima aquí la necesidad de preservar la vinculación entre el nombre propio originario y su uso como común". En realidad creo que decís lo mismo, dado que "preservar la vinculación" puede referirse a lo que comentas de no modificar la escritura para evitar confusiones.

Comment: El DPD (http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=alzheimer) coincide con Fundeu en el uso de minúsculas y tilde: "... si se utiliza aisladamente para referirse a dicha enfermedad, se convierte en un sustantivo común, por lo que ha de escribirse con minúscula inicial y con tilde ..."

Comment: Es fácil que respuestas dadas aquí sean mejores que las de la RAE :-) Ya lo hemos visto unas cuantas veces. +1 (en el otro caso "el nombre propio originario" era _tweeter_  y sin embargo se decidieron por la forma como suena en inglés y salieron con tuit. Ridículo)